# Do .Net Core Command Line (CLI) come with Visual Studio 2015 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am trying to compile a C# program using .Net Core Command ine (CLI) tools.
I have Visual Studio 2015 installed but when I type:

```
> dotnet
```

at the command line to see all the options I don't get anything.
Is this supposed to come with Visual Studio 2015?
I am running VS 2015 Update 3 right now and will try again after.
But if I have to download and install anything I hope it does not corrupt anything.

---

Here are the steps I have done so far:

1) Removed "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables" both x86 and 64 versions.

2) Reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and no longer get errors that Redistributable install failed.

3) Installed Microsoft ASP.Net and WebTools update. (from Tools -> Extensions -> Visual Studio Gallery).
I got an error trying to install here so had to run this line:

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

from the command prompt.

Then the install works.

Now I am able to type:

```
>dotnet
```

and

```
>dotnet --version
```

and

```
>dotnet --help
```

and see the feedback.

But for

```
>dotnet repl
```

I am getting:
"No executable found matching command "dotnet-repl".

Does anyone know why this is happening?

---

It turns out dotnet repl is not available in Preview 2 but will be available later via tools - extensions.

Moving on to try and build an application with:

```
>dotnet new
```

Comment: According to the [installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) you need to install the [.net core tools](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245) as well as VS 2015

Answer (score 1):

You need use Basic commands with `dotnet` which are- `new, restore, run, build, test, publish, pack`

To create simple Hello World application, use commands following way-

```
dotnet new
```

This will creates a new .NET Core project.

```
dotnet restore
```

This will restores the dependencies and tools of a project specified in the project.json file.

```
dotnet run
```

This command will run your application.

Refer this for more information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/index

You can also develop .NET Core apps (without VS2015) from the command-line by downloading the .NET Core SDK for Windows - https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=809122 (which you already installed)

---

**EDIT:**

With regards to `dotnet repl` command, They have removed `repl` from dotnet common commands. Refer this issue - https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3913

Comment: I think if you just type "> dotnet" it is supposed to show you all the commands.  That is the test. Right?

Comment: Any idea what this means?
"No executable found matching command "dotnet-repl"
when I type ">dotnet repl"?

Comment: I think they have removed `repl` from dotnet common commands. Look at this issue - https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3913